# Is there a reason this doesn't work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

A simple HTML form:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="/view/album/id/4"><ol>
<li class="no-padding"><div class="element">

<input type="hidden" name="media" value="" id="media" /></div></li>
<li class="no-padding"><div class="button">
<input type="submit" name="add_to_favorites" id="add_to_favorites" value="Add To Favorites" /></div></li></ol></form>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#add_to_favorites').hover(function() {
    var id = 10;
    // alert(id);
    $('#media').val(id);
});
```

Which basically means that when you hover over the submit button of the form, the jQuery will set 10 as value of the #media hidden field.

When I click on the submit button though, the hidden field returns NULL:

```
var_dump($_POST);
// this will return:
// array(2) { ["media"]=>  NULL ["add_to_favorites"]=>  NULL }
```

EDIT:

I tested both value of "var id" and the hidden field value with alert() and they are properly set.

EDIT2:

There is one click() event triggered on the page, too, here's the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box-content2 a').click(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('href');
        var title = $('img', this).attr('alt');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#media-photo img').attr('src', path);
        $('#media-photo img').attr('alt', title);
        $('#media-photo img').attr('id', id);
        return false;
    });

    $('#add_to_favorites').hover(function() {
        var id = 10;
        $('#media').val(id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hang on.  So you've checked that the hidden field is having its value set correctly and it is?  So it's the submit click event that is causing the value to be nulled again?

Comment: Did you try changing it to .click instead of .hover, to see if it would work on a click event?  Perhaps the trouble is with the hovering.

Comment: I tested your form code and your jQuery, and it worked fine on my test page.  Are there any onsubmit events being triggered?

Comment: @zombat: No. There is just one other click() event triggered which should not be the problem but I'm going to add it to my post.

Comment: Interesting thing is that the submit button is NULL, too.

Comment: @Phil: Yes. I did alert($('#media').val()); and it shows me '10' so it is set correctly. But when I submit the form everything is set to NULL for some strange reason (including the submit button).

Comment: Could you post the entire html content of the page?  I've had a situation where an improperly constructed "script" tag would prevent JQuery from working properly.

Comment: I managed to figure out another way to achieve what I want, I got rid of the hidden field and instead I add the id to the URL with jQuery on hover() event and then I get the id from the request object in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is Val() only gets the input value of the first matched element so you can't use it to set a single property to a value, to set a property on a matched element use the attr function like this  attr( key, value )

more details check [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) and [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val)

Comment: From your second link: val( val ) Set the value attribute of every matched element. In jQuery 1.2, this is also able to set the value of select elements, but selecting the appropriate options.

Comment: Eh??
That's just plain wrong.  Val() gets a value from an input element; val(arg) sets a value to an input element.  That set value should then be available for form posts.  It's in the same documentation you just linked to.

Comment: @John Fisher : what does that do with my answer ?

Comment: Oops.  I focused on the "first matched element so you can't" part of the answer, missing the "can't use it to set", which is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should have two functions defined for your hover event.  One for mouseover and one for mouseout.  So your hover event will look like:

```
$('#add_to_favorites').hover(function() {
    var id = 10;
    // alert(id);
    $('#media').val(id);
}, function() {
    // Probably do nothing here.
});
```

Perhaps you'd be better off binding to the mouseover event?

Comment: That's not the problem (you don't have to define function for mouseout) - when I define function also for mouseout it still returns NULL.